# Using RX to synchronize multiple events

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Let's say I have three products in a list. In order to enable a certain action, all three need to be of a certain type.  In order to find out the type of the product, I need to make a service call and wait for a response.

What I would like to do is wait for all three responses (maybe with a timeout in case something goes wrong) and when all the info is gathered, decide whether or not to enable the possible action.

I used to solve this by having some counter or reset events to keep track of the finished events but I would like to see if I can use Rx to do it in a cleaner way.

As I am not too familiar with Rx yet, I am looking for some tips/pointers.  I understand I can use

```
Observable.FromEventPattern
```

for the events I am waiting on.  I subscribe and wait for the response and handle it. I am just not clear on how to combine the multiple events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The combinator you are looking for is `CombineLatest`

Say you've got a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public delegate void FooEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);

    public event FooEventHandler FirstEvent = delegate {};    
    public event FooEventHandler SecondEvent = delegate {};    
    public event FooEventHandler ThirdEvent = delegate {};    

    public void DoIt()
    {
        FireOne();
        FireTwo();
        FireThree();
    }

    public void FireOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Firing event 1...");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        FirstEvent(this, new EventArgs());
    }
    public void FireTwo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Firing event 2...");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        SecondEvent(this, new EventArgs());
    }
    public void FireThree()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Firing event 3...");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        ThirdEvent(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

First you'd want to "convert" those events to `Observable`:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var firstWatcher = Observable.FromEventPattern(foo, "FirstEvent");
var secondWatcher = Observable.FromEventPattern(foo, "SecondEvent");
var thirdWatcher = Observable.FromEventPattern(foo, "ThirdEvent");
```

Now you'll want the "Only fire when all these have fired" selector, which is `CombineLatest`:

```
var allDone = Observable.CombineLatest(firstWatcher, secondWatcher, thirdWatcher);
```

And to test it out:

```
using(allDone.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("Boop! You sunk my battleship!")))
{
    foo.DoIt();
}
```

Alternative "test harness":

```
var foo = new Foo();
var firstWatcher = Observable.FromEventPattern(foo, "FirstEvent");
var secondWatcher = Observable.FromEventPattern(foo, "SecondEvent");
var thirdWatcher = Observable.FromEventPattern(foo, "ThirdEvent");

var allDone = Observable.CombineLatest(firstWatcher, secondWatcher, thirdWatcher);

// keep a handle on the subscription            
IDisposable subscription = null;

// to prevent premature exiting...
var blocker = new ManualResetEvent(false);

// explicit subscribe
subscription = allDone.Subscribe(
    whoCares => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BOOM! We're done!");
        // always clean up after yourself
        if(subscription != null)
        {
            subscription.Dispose();
        }
        // it's ok, we can quit now
        blocker.Set();
    });

foo.DoIt();

// Wait until it's clear to go ahead...
blocker.WaitOne();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help JerKimball. Very useful.  How about if the events are async, for example if we called FireOne|Two|Three and these events returned immediately after making some async call without triggering the event?  I tried it with my events and it looks like the using(allDone...) will exit before the events are finished and therefore the allDone handler does not get called (unless I am doing something wrong).

Comment: For instance, do you have an example of how to make your current sample work if public void FireOne() contained `int msDelay = 8000;
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(msDelay))
                .ContinueWith((Task starter) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("EVENT 1");
                        FirstEvent(this, new EventArgs());
                    }, TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning);`

Comment: What's actually happening is that in my crappy little example-harness, the program is "ending" before the events fire - more to the point, the subscription that is created in `allDone.Subscribe` is being disposed. Put a `Console.ReadLine`, `Thread.Sleep(10000)`, or anything you want before the closing brace of that `using` (alternatively, store the `IDisposable` it creates and dispose it yourself)